# Android Spinner in Toolbar showing Text but not Image

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar

**menu_catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/catalogactivityfilter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@mipmap/filter"
        android:title="Sort"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        />
</menu>
```

**In my Fragment**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu);
        setUpFilter(menu);


    }

    public void setUpFilter(Menu menu){
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.catalogactivityfilter);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.array_sorting_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

In my `toolbar`, i am getting the `spinner` but it is not displaying the image  when i open the app,instead it shows options.I want to set the image of `catalogactivityfilter` when app opens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and override `getView` and `getDropDownView`

Here is a custom adapter I made that uses `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` to set a drawable in the textview.
You can simply use it like this:

```
spinner.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this));
```

**CustomSpinnerAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemsEnum> {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0, ItemsEnum.values());
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView= (CheckedTextView) convertView;

        if (checkedTextView== null) {
            checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) mLayoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  parent, false);
        }
        ItemsEnum item = getItem(position);
        checkedTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
        checkedTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.getResId(), 0, 0, 0);

        return checkedTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView;

        if (checkedTextView == null) {
            checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) mLayoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  parent, false);
        }
        ItemsEnum item = getItem(position);
        checkedTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
        checkedTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.getResId(), 0, 0, 0);

        return checkedTextView;
    }
}
```

**ItemsEnum.java**

```
enum ItemsEnum {
OPTION1("Option 1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher),
OPTION2("Options 2", R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

private String title;
private  Integer resId;

ItemsEnum(String title, Integer resId){
    this.title = title;
    this.resId = resId;
}

public Integer getResId() {
    return resId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
}
```